# hashSHA1 hash& SHA256 importation from hashes

Tags: python, hash, hashcode, sha256, sha1

I am trying to just import hashSHA1 & hashSHA256 with the below command, but it raise the below error.
When I tried ti open **init**.py I found it empty, I used pip install hashes but that would  not solve the issue, I also tried to uninstall the "hashes" and reinstall it but that would not help.

```py
from hashes import hashSHA256, hashSHA1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0ed88c6be330> in <module>
      7 from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_der_public_key
      8 
----> 9 from hashes import hashSHA256, hashSHA1
     10 
     11 

ImportError: cannot import name 'hashSHA256' from 'hashes' (C:\Users\A784592\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hashes\__init__.py)
```

Comment: It is compatible, the code run o.k for multiple times but I know what happened suddenly

Comment: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/cryptographic-hashes/

Comment: Thanks @James yes I guess no need to import hashSHA1 & hash SHA256 just hashes.SHA256 & hashes.SHA1